# Quickest way to find position of item less than or equal to double in sorted list C#

Tags: c#, list, loops, sorting

I am exploring the fastest way to iterate through three sorted lists to find the position of the first item which is equal to or less than a double value. The lists contains two columns of doubles.

I have the two following **working** examples attached below, these are encompassed by a bigger while loop  (which also modifies the currentPressure list changing the [0] value)  value. But, considering the amount of rows (500,000+) being parsed by the bigger while loop, the code below is too slow (one iteration of the three while loops takes >20 ms).

"allPressures" contains all rows while currentPressure is modified by the remaining code. The while loops are used to align the time from the Flow, Rpm and Position lists to the Time in the pressure list.

In other words I am trying to find the quickest way to determine the x of
for instance

```
FlowList[x].Time =< currentPressure[0].Time
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Examples:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < allPressures.Count; i++)
            {
                if (FlowList[i].Time >= currentPressure[0].Time)
                {
                    fl = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < allPressures.Count; i++)
            {
                if (RpmList[i].Time >= currentPressure[0].Time)
                {
                    rp = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < allPressures.Count; i++)
            {
                if (PositionList[i].Time >= currentPressure[0].Time)
                {
                    bp = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Using while loop:

```
            while (FlowList[fl].Time < currentPressure[0].Time)
            {
                fl++;
            }

            while (RpmList[rp].Time < currentPressure[0].Time)
            {
                rp++;
            }

            while (PositionList[bp].Time < currentPressure[0].Time)
            {
                bp++;
            }
```

Comment: Is it an option to change the data structure to a dictionary or a binary tree instead of a list? Or BinarySearch extension method of a List<T>: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Two words: binary search.

Comment: Two more words, if you're doing some sort of time-based processing where events follow each other chronologically: priority queue.

Comment: Have a look at [Array.BinarySearch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba2bttb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: What are the datatypes of `FlowList`, `RpmList` and `PositionList`? These are list of *whats*?

Comment: And these 500,000 *rows* of yours are not coming from a database, right?

Comment: The 500,000 rows are all stored in memory, and they are of type double.

Comment: @Henrik_er, can you please clarify what the types of `FlowList`, `RpmList`, `PositionList`, and `currentPressure` are?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride See Comment above. They are all of type double.

Comment: @Henrik_er, but a `double` does not have property called `Time`. How is your custom type defined that has this property? *This* is the type we are wondering about, not the type of `Time`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, a sorry. It's been a long day. Yes they are defined as follows:
`internal class PressureData
    {
        public double Pressure { get; set; }
        public double Time { get; set; }
    }` and elsewhere in the method `List<PressureData> PressureList = new List<PressureData>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are doing a linear search. This means that in the worst case scenario your are iterating over all the elements in your lists. This gives you a computational complexity of `O(3*n)` where `n` is the length of your lists and `3` is the number of lists you are searching.

Since your lists are sorted you can use the much faster *binary search* which has a complexity of `O(log(n))` and in your case `O(3*log(n))`.

Luckily you don't have to implement it yourself, because .NET offers the helper method [List.BinarySearch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6(v=vs.110).aspx). You will need the one that takes a custom comparer, because you want to compare `PressureData` objects.

Since you are looking for the index of the closest value that's less than your search value, you'll have to use a little trick: when `BinarySearch()` doesn't find a matching value it returns the index of the next element that is larger than the search value. From this it's easy to find the previous element that is smaller than the search value.

Here is an extension method the implements this:

```
public static int FindMaxIndex<T>(
    this List<T> sortedList, T inclusiveUpperBound, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    var index = sortedList.BinarySearch(inclusiveUpperBound, comparer);

    // The max value was found in the list. Just return its index.
    if (index >= 0)
        return index;

    // The max value was not found and "~index" is the index of the
    // next value greater than the search value.
    index = ~index;

    // There are values in the list less than the search value.
    // Return the index of the closest one.
    if (index > 0)
        return index - 1;

    // All values in the list are greater than the search value.
    return -1;
}
```

Test it at https://dotnetfiddle.net/kLZsM5

Use this method with a comparer that understands `PressureData` objects:

```
var pdc = Comparer<PressureData>.Create((x, y) => x.Time.CompareTo(y.Time));
var fl = FlowList.FindMaxIndex(currentPressure[0], pdc);
```

Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dmgzsv

Comment: Allocating three arrays of 500 000 doubles in a loop is almost certainly much slower than even the naive linear search currently used. Use `IComparer<MyCustomBaseType>` or `IComparer<double>` from a `Func<T, double>` property selector or three separate comparers if the lists are already arrays. If all else fails, write out the binary search loop manually. Anything but `.Select(...).ToArray()` in a loop.

Comment: Currently testing the time spent on the various methods suggested. Would this method possibly be the quickest if I convert the FlowList and so forth to arrays before the loop, and thus avoid the .Select(.....).ToArray() ?

Comment: @Henrik_er: if you don't modify the lists, then yes. If you do modify the lists, then converting back and forth between `List` and `Array` is hopelessly inefficient. Besides, the whole thing is a bit unnecessary because `List<T>.BinarySearch` exists, it just has no parameter for the value, meaning you have to produce a custom comparer (`Comparer.Create`) that is slightly more difficult and incorporates the value to search for.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, right the projection into an array should of course be outside the main loop or best be avoided we a more sophisticated comparer. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Henrik_er, there might be a problem with doing a simple binary search. Please see the addendum to my answer and clarify whether this this is the case.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, as suspected the distances are virtually equidistant so the answer should work. Will test it in a little while.

Comment: @Henrik_er, erm... I made a major mistake when writing the comparer. The last addendum should show the correct now. I hope... Also it compares `PressureData` objects directly now.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride it seems to be working well when the interval is constant. In one of my lists on the other hand, the interval change like this 5 - 8 - 5, in other words there is a jump of 8 seconds before returning to 5. On this occurrence, the comparer breaks down and return a negative number... The comparer in question returned ...26,27,-29 and it breaks.

Comment: @Henrik_er, turns out is all much easier than expected. `BinarySearch()` does almost exactly what you need. I deleted most of the rubbish I wrote so far and updated the answer with a more sane solution. This will also solve your problem with the nonuniform intervals.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride The last revision works perfectly. Thanks for helping me getting on top of BinarySearch() and list extensions!